# Draw following set in $\Bbb{R}^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, visualization

How can I draw following set in $\Bbb{R}^3$?

$$
M = \left\{(x,y,z) : \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le z \le 1 \right\}
$$

I have the answer in the book but I don't want to check it before i try to solve it first, so I prefer some hints instead of the answer.

edit: Should I just first check $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le z$ and then check $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le z$ with $z = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<z$ looks like for a fixed $z\le 1$, then try varying $z$ to get an idea of what it looks like in $\mathbb{R}^3$.